# Pentaho report generation - white space in value (Springboot service)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have created a springboot service for report generation using "Pentaho Reporting Engine Classic version 7.0.0.0-25.-1"

Issue:- different output compared to PRD.. On generation of HTML(other format) output

**PRD's output**

```
<td valign="middle" class="style-7">ABC-1001-1700860</td>
```

Related style is

```
.style-7 {
    color: black; 
    font-size: 8pt; 
    font-family: "Arial"; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-style: normal; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-align: left; 
    word-spacing: 0pt; 
    letter-spacing: 0pt; 
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    border-bottom: 1pt solid #ccccff; 
    border-right: 1pt solid #ccccff
}
```

**From Service**

```
<td valign="middle" class="style-4">ABC-1001-1 700860</td>
```

Related style

```
.style-4 {
    color: black; 
    font-size: 8pt; 
    font-family: "Arial"; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-style: normal; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-align: left; 
    word-spacing: 0pt; 
    letter-spacing: 0pt; 
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    border-bottom: 1pt solid #ccccff; 
    border-right: 1pt solid #ccccff
}
```

issue:-

1. CSS class name is different(but no difference, so ok..)
2. There is space in data.

Why space(ABC-1001-1 700860) is appearing? How to get exact output as PRD?

How to get latest pentaho(8 onwards) jars. as well?

Comment: Can you tell us what you call "From Service" ?

Answer (score 0):

The Report designer let you define different format for HTML, File, PDF,...

I know it can be disturbing because you easily make a mistake = involuntary setup.

To tell you more, we need to know were ABC-1001-1(?)700860 comes from: direct input from database/csv or formula.

Pentaho V8 will not be published before December, and V7.1 is the last version. Watch [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Report%20Designer/)!

Comment: @ AlainD given some more detail above... We can give full width of field because its not fixed length value.. any clue.. any jar which need to be changed?

Comment: Postgres, a database table then. What is "ABC-1001-1 700860" ? A column read from the database? A column computed by SQL in the database? If yes what is the formula? A column computed with report designer? If yes what is the formula?

Comment: Its just select query.. I am using same prpt file for PRD and service.. field propery text-wrap= wrap, word-break=true, direction-ltr...  similar issue is raised http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PRD-5917 ... is there any settings for classic-engine.properties?

Comment: Is  the column which defines "ABC-1001-1 700860" a simple unique field or is it a concatenation ?

Answer (score 0):

@AlainD thanks for the response.. I am getting data from Database(Postgres) using JNDI..
Basic code

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 HtmlReportUtil.createStreamHTML(report, baos);
```

roport object is 
final MasterReport report

Setting ContentType based on format like text/html,application/pdf 
characterset is UTF-8

SpringBoot(tomcat): 1.5.2.RELEASE

```
<td valign="middle" class="style-7">ABCD STORE-2F</td>
<td valign="middle" class="style-7">ABC-1001-1 700860</td>
```

some analysis..

if value contains space within it then its coming properly..ABCD STORE-2F.. value is correct.

if there there is no space and some spacial character then space is getting added.. ABC-1001-1(space)700860

[pentaho PRD vs Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnjOx.png)

by seeing above image we can see the clear difference in the display.. 
is there any word wrapping issue..

service -- M-N-IM-A001-MD8-1 000

PRD -- M-N-IM-A001-MD8-1000

i believe that there should not be any difference.

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean by "Service"? Pentaho BA?

Comment: You mean you are using this https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0L0/0Y0/090 ? And the report is run by this step: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pentaho+Reporting+Output ?